# How do I mirror my iPhone screen to my iPad?

Tags: airplay

How can I mirror my iPhone SE to my iPad Pro under iOS 10? There is a web site that says this is supported via AirPlay but I cannot get the iPad to show up as a destination for my iPhone, I can only get Apple TVs to show up there. The official Apple support documentation I have found only talks about Apple TVs as being the destination for screen mirroring and does not mention mirroring an iPhone to an iPad.

Comment: Apple has never allowed AirPlay from one iOS device to another iOS device, regardless of the OS.  What site is telling you this is possible?

Comment: I am struggling to find an answer to this as well, from iphone 7 to ipad (both running iOS 11). Any 3rd party solutions for this?